# How do I force a column break in the reference/bibliography page of the paper?

Tags: bibliographies, two-column

[image: My output is like this]I need to display my paper's reference side-by-side, to balance the page. I have tried `\vfill`,`\coloumnbreak` in the `.bib` file, but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to force it to move content into the second column. I have included bibliography through:
                        \bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
                         \bibliography{strings,refs}

[image: but i want it to be like this]

Comment: Welcome! There is no need to shout, though. However much you scream, we can't help you unless you help us by editing your question to give us more information. We need code for a minimal document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem. Right now, I doubt anybody could even guess. However, putting things like that in the `.bib` file is only going to end in tears. Or maybe not. Probably it will just do nothing, which is not bad, all things considered. You need to customise `\printbibliography` to use two columns, if need be. Or switch to two columns first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.bib` file only contains the content, not the format. You need to play with the style files to change the formatting of references if you want to manually add formatting elements. However there are some solutions that doesn't require you to get lost in the style files.

One option is the [balance](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/balance?lang=en) package. Add `\usepackage{balance}` and put `\balance` before your references in your main file.

Another option is the [flushend](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flushend) package. Just add it as `\usepackage{flushend}` and magic happens.